# Getting a zone's location via gcloud cli

Tags: google-cloud-sdk

Is there a way to get the Location value of a zone/region via the gcloud cli? I'm looking for the values listed here: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones

I'm hoping to use these values to mark locations on a geochart.

Thanks!

Comment: For security reasons, the actual physical location of a zone is not published. The CLI will display names, which provide a rough location, but not geolocation information.

Comment: What about the locations in the link above?

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: The locations seem to be published in the docs: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones

Was just hoping I could get these values via the cli. I'll just maintain my own list. Thanks!

Comment: You need to be clear what you are asking. If you mean the geolocation (exact location), that is not published. If you are looking for "somewhere in the vicinity" then use the locations mentioned in the docs.

Comment: Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a zones location via gloud cli using the following commmand: `gcloud compute zones list`.

You can check in [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/zones/list) the other parameters that you can use.

Comment: Well aware of this. However, the values returned seem limited to the following: NAME                       REGION                   STATUS  NEXT_MAINTENANCE  TURNDOWN_DATE

Also, if there are additional fields I can't seem to find them.

Answer (score 0):

Maintaining my own list of locations by referring to: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/regions-zones